# Error in R: Error in UseMethod("index<-")

Tags: r

Im trying to calculate spi values for 2011-2021 but I keep getting an error even though my code is identical to that from an example in github.

here's my code:

```
spi4 <- standardized.index(data = ngong_data_, agg.length = 90, 
                           index.out = dates, ref.years = NA, 
                           ref.length = 10)
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```r
Error in UseMethod("index<-") : 
  no applicable method for 'index<-' applied to an object of class  
  "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you please include which libraries you're using?  Typically either as part of your code chunk or as additional tags or (ideally) both.  This will help people reproduce your issue and make it more likely that someone can assist.

Comment: Thank you. I used the following libraries: standaRdized, FAdist, SPEI,dplyr, xts,zoo

Comment: `xtx` and `zoo` each have a function `index()` as well - there may be masking between your packages.

Comment: According to the documentation, you must pass an xts object to `standardized.index` and not a tibble.

Comment: I have tried detaching either but I get an error that they're both needed by the standaRdized package, thus they fail to detach.

Comment: I suggest you try to understand my comment.